# Console.WriteLine Method in c# is not writing its argument but the argument from another class

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I've created a blank solution in witch I have two different projects: "HelloCSharp" and "PrintMyName". In the first project there is a class with the following source code:

namespace HelloCSharp
{

```
class HelloCSharp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, C#!");
    }
}
```

}

In the "PrintMyName" project there is a class with the following source code:

```
namespace PrintMyName
{

class PrintMyName
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Rosen");
    }
}
}
```

When I try to run this program, the method doesn't write the argument "Rosen" but the argument from the another class "Hello, C#!".

I try with alternative code but the result is the same ("Hello, C#!"):

```
namespace PrintMyName
{
class PrintMyName
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String myFirstName = "Rosen";
        System.Console.WriteLine(myFirstName);
    }
}
}
```

If someone have an idea what's the reason of this problem and how can I print my name, please send me an answer!
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're not running the second project at all. Make sure the PrintMyName project is your startup project by right clicking it and selecting 'Set as startup project'.

Comment: If its not above then someone is playing a cruel prank on you and replaced your reference to System with one that forces console.writeline to always output "Hello, C#!"

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not running the program you think you're running. Check that the correct project is set as start-up project in Visual Studio.

To change it, right click the project you want to run, and look for `Set Start Up Project` (with a gear wheel symbol).